# Dialogflow API v2 integration issue

Tags: android, dialogflow-es

I am using **Dialogflow v1** on android but I want to use **V2** because it provides more features and because the V1 will be [deprecated](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v1-v2-migration-guide) on October 23, 2019. However I can't **integrate API V2 to my codes**. Here is the **V1** code:

```
private void initChatbot() {
    final AIConfiguration config = new AIConfiguration("Here put Client access token",
            AIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages.English,
            AIConfiguration.RecognitionEngine.System);
    aiDataService = new AIDataService(this, config);
    customAIServiceContext = AIServiceContextBuilder.buildFromSessionId(uuid);// helps to create new session whenever app restarts
    aiRequest = new AIRequest();
}
```

Here is the **V2** code:

```
private void initV2Chatbot() {
    try {
        InputStream stream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test_agent_credentials);
        GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(stream);
        String projectId = ((ServiceAccountCredentials)credentials).getProjectId();

        SessionsSettings.Builder settingsBuilder = SessionsSettings.newBuilder();
        SessionsSettings sessionsSettings = settingsBuilder.setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials)).build();
        sessionsClient = SessionsClient.create(sessionsSettings);
        session = SessionName.of(projectId, uuid);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I wrote this code for **V2** got this error:

```
error: cannot find symbol variable test_agent_credentials
```

I actually don't know what is test_agent_credentials and why I should use it. Can anybody tell me where I should put my console.cloud.google Dialogflow İntegration Key Id?

Here is the Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tyagiabhinav.dialogflowchat"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }


    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    // Java V2
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-oauth2:v1-rev145-1.25.0'


    // Dialogflow SDK dependencies
    implementation 'ai.api:sdk:2.0.7@aar'
    implementation 'ai.api:libai:1.6.12'

    // Java V2
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-dialogflow:0.67.0-alpha'
    // for Remote Procedure Call to avoid "No functional channel service provider found" error while creating SessionsClient
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.15.1'
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`R.raw.test_agent_credentials` refers to the `test_agent_credentials.json` file that is presumed to be in the raw resource folder. This JSON file contains the full credentials file that you downloaded when you [created the Dialogflow Integration service account](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v2-auth-setup#getting_the_service_account_key).

Ignore the section about using the key. It uses the `gloud` command to generate the key to use in the auth header. You're doing this with the `GoogleCredentials.fromStream()` call.

The important part was from step 10 before where you save the JSON key file and make it available to Android as a raw resource. See [this information](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources) about Android resources and, in particular, the section about raw resources. Raw resources should be placed under the "resource" folder in a sub-folder called "raw". The name of the file you save there should match the part of the resource name after `R.raw` without the "json" extension.

Comment: Sir, i looked at the link you wrote. My English not really good, so i didn't solve the issue. I did well until "Using the key" part. Can you please help me on this?

Comment: Updated answer to clarify.

Comment: Sir, sorry but i didn’t go far. The question is: where should i put my .json ? R.raw.(json doc), where should i put the json , codes find it?

Comment: Hopefully clarified.

Comment: I really thank you, sir. You saved me from a big effort.